# What kind of trick do Twitter use about css outline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, outline

When I click the buttons on a timeline, my browser(chrome) doesn't focus the button. The focus was stay on the element where it was. How do they do that?

[image]

These are what I found.

- They don't use `blur()` function on click. If they call the method, the preexisting focus would disappear.
- It seems they don't save previous focused element, and refocus it. When I overrided `$.fn.focus` method, it wasn't called.
- They use some trick with JavaScript. When I disabled JavaScript, I managed to focus the element by clicking the buttons.

Comment: My guess (without looking at the code): They use `mouseup` instead of `click` and prevent the default action. Have you found the code for the buttons that triggers the action and shows the popup?

Comment: No, I haven't. And, when I tested, it was not possible to prevent focusing clicked elements by preventing the default action.

Comment: Hm, what about preventing the `focus` event's action?

Answer (score 0):

What you wanna do is focus on an element whenever you someone clicks on a certain element.

[Click here to check out an example of how I would do it](http://jsfiddle.net/ProgrammerKid/n0vqs3ny/2/F)

This is what you are looking for

```
6 |    searchButton.focus();
```

**UPDATE:**
Your question is unclear, and you question is how does it keep the focus on the same element... and I showed you how..

Comment: That's not what I want. Please read my question more carefully.:)